# combine multiple php files into one

Tags: php

I'm trying to combine several php files in to one larger with php.

I'm sending form data to a small files and use includes to load into them in a
main page.

With many of these files each time I work an inspection project is getting to be a little time consuming dropping to a command prompt.

I'm able to combine pages with a command prompt using the "cat" command and pull the ones not yet completed.

```
cat page-1.php page-2.php page-3.php page-4.php page-5.php page-6.php page-7.php page-8.php page-9.php page-10.php page-11.php page-12.php >> newpage.php
```

I need help with php to perform this with out having to execute a shell command from php.

I also need the code to ignore missing files and continue with the rest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about the good ol' `include`? Or a `foreach()` within `glob()` to retrieve all files from a directory.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for include()

Comment: I mentioned I already did this, but with many pages and files I decided to hard code and combine would eliminate any mixups and make additional pages easier to manage.

Comment: Is this a different problem to your question from yesterday?

Comment: beware that `<?php` is not always followed by `?>` at the end of the document. when merging like this you may run into `<?php ..... <?php` giving a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will keep them in the order they need to be. The other way does not keep them in order and will display errors.

```
<?php

 $txt1 = file_get_contents('page-001.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-002.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-003.php');

 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-004.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-005.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-006.php');

 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-007.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-008.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-009.php');

 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-010.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-011.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-012.php');

 $fp = fopen('newcombined.php', 'w');
 if(!$fp)
   die('Could not create / open text file for writing.');
   if(fwrite($fp, $txt1) === false)
   die('Could not write to text file.');

  echo 'Text files have been merged.';    

 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
   $code.=file_get_contents("./$filename");
}
file_put_contents("./combined.php",$code);
```

Run that in your target directory. That reads all your php files in the directory, extracts their code and then combines and saves it in your new file.

Comment: I like the looks of this ;)

Comment: Thanks :) Although its pretty useless because for PHP interpreter its negligible difference whether all those code files were included separately or together. This requirement just looks like a *round up*